# plot using PyX with Strings and Floats

Tags: python, pyx

I have a list: [ [List of dates(string)] [List of values(floats) ]
How can i make plot of it using PyX?

```
g.plot(graph.data.values(x=values[0], y=values[1]))
```

is not working

Answer (score 0):

While there is no proper timeaxis support in PyX, you can do something along the lines of

http://sourceforge.net/p/pyx/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/pyx/test/functional/test_timeaxis.py